# Не работает inet_ntop, что делаю не так?

Tags: delphi, winsock

На delphi получаю список локальных IP адресов машины (IPv4 и IPv6). Выдержка из кода (цикл убрал, чтобы не раздувать код):

```
function inet_ntop(Family: integer; pAddr: pointer; pStringBuf: PAnsiChar;  StringBufSize: DWORD): PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll';

var
  size: LongInt;
  rv:DWORD;
  adapter_addresses :  PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES;
  i,j: LongInt;
  ua : PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS;
  pAddr : sockaddr_in;
  family:Integer;
  tempStr:String;

begin
rv := GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, 0, nil, adapter_addresses, @size);
ua := adapter_addresses^.FirstUnicastAddress;
pAddr:=PSockAddrIn(ua^.Address.lpSocketaddr)^;
family:=ua^.Address.lpSocketaddr.sa_family;
      case family of
      AF_INET:
          Writeln('IP ProtocolFamily="IPv4": '+inet_ntoa(pAddr.sin_addr));
      AF_INET6: // ipv6
        begin
          tempStr:='';
          tempStr:= Inet_ntop(family, Pointer(pAddr.sin_addr), PChar(tempStr), INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
          Writeln('IP ProtocolFamily="IPv6": '+ tempStr);
        end;

      else
        Writeln('IP n="'+IntToStr(j)+'": Unknown protocol family');
      end;
```

В случае IPv4 результат правильный, а для IPv6 всегда возвращается пустая строка. ЧЯДнТ?
WSAGetLastError возвращает ошибку 10022 (Invalid argument). Чего ему надо-то?

Answer (score 1):

`pAddr [in]`
A pointer to the IP address in network byte to convert to a string.

When the `Family` parameter is `AF_INET`, then the `pAddr` parameter must point to an `IN_ADDR` structure with the IPv4 address to convert.

When the `Family` parameter is `AF_INET6`, then the `pAddr` parameter must point to an `IN6_ADDR` structure with the IPv6 address to convert.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

У вас `pAddr : sockaddr_in;` для IPv6 нужно `sockaddr_in6`;

Comment: Я интуитивно догадывался :-) Спасибо.  Добавил:
 `pAddrIPv6:=PsockAddrIn6(ua^.Address.lpSocketaddr)^;
          tempStr:= Inet_ntop(family, pAddrIPv6.sin6_addr, PChar(tempStr), INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);` 

Теперь падает при выполнении... Не подскажете ,а то что-то запутался...

Answer (score 0):

[Похожий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157151/isnt-struct-sockadr-in-supposed-to-work-for-both-ipv4-and-ipv6) вопрос на английском СО. Дело в том, `sockaddr_in` используется для протокола IPv4, для IPv6 нужно использовать `sockaddr_in6`.